# How can I generate robot framework documentation (libdoc) on a directory

Tags: robotframework

I have a few python library files in a directory. All the files together are used for test automation purpose. Is there a way to generate documentation of the keywords in all the files in that directory (using libdoc or any other tool). That way we can have the user know about all the keywords available in the automation library, without knowing what library files exist. So basically I want to generate one document for all the python files in a directory. Is that possible ? Is there any other alternatives to achieve the same ?

Answer (score 4):

One alternative is to use the [robotframework hub](https://github.com/boakley/robotframework-hub/wiki). The hub is a personal web app that you can point at a folder to provide documentation for all keywords at or below that folder. (Note: I am the author of this package)

You can also use the [robot framework docs manager](http://rfdocs.org/). It is roughly similar in concept to the hub, but more powerful (and arguably more complex).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried using it and it worked just like what I want. I have two questions. (1) I am using it from Linux, Why do I need the desktop to be installed. Can I not use this tool without ubuntu-desktop installed ? (2) I see the parent class functions also show up as keywords in the child. Is there an option when generating the keyword to disable the parent class functions showing up in the child. that way I think it will be more clean for an user, especially because you provided the keyword search.

Comment: I think its not the parent-child... its the "from class import *" thats causing this.

Comment: @user3517560: you wrote "I tried using it". What is "it"? The hub? The doc manager? What do you mean "need the desktop to be installed"? What desktop?

Comment: Hi Brian I used the hub that you wrote. When running the 'Python -rfhub ****" I got error saying that there is no Xserver running. When I tried to run on a different Linux box with Ubuntu UI (desktop UI) installed it worked. 
Then is my other previously posted question

Comment: @user3517560: if you get an error about requiring an xserver running, that's a bug. I can't imagine why it would require that. Please submit a complete bug report with a full stacktrace at https://github.com/boakley/robotframework-hub/issues and I'll fix it if I can reproduce it.

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet will generate code for resource (`.robot`) or library (`.py`) files recursively and place the HTML files in a separate folder with the same folder structure as your input files.

Try it without the `shutil.rmtree(...)` before the `for` loop, just in case.

```
import os
import shutil

in_path = <full path to input files>
out_path = <full path to output files>

shutil.rmtree(out_path, ignore_errors=True)
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(in_path):
    for file in files:
        splitext = os.path.splitext(file)
        if splitext[1] == '.robot':
            rel_path = os.path.relpath(root, in_path)
            in_file = os.path.join(root, file)
            out_dir = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(out_path, rel_path))
            out_file = os.path.join(out_dir, splitext[0] + '.html')

            if not os.path.exists(out_dir):
                os.makedirs(out_dir)
            libdoc(in_file, out_file, docformat='ROBOT')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import subprocess

extensions = [".robot"]
root_dir = "<LOCATION>"
output_folder = "<LOCATION>"

if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
    os.makedirs(output_folder)

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(root_dir):
    for filename in filenames:
        if any(filename.endswith(ext) for ext in extensions):
            file_path = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
            output_file = os.path.join(output_folder, os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + ".html")
            subprocess.call(["py", "-m", "robot.testdoc", file_path, output_file])
            
            
                            
            
            
import os
import subprocess

extensions = [".resource"]
root_dir = "<LOCATION>"

output_dir = os.path.join(root_dir, "output")

if not os.path.exists(output_dir):
    os.makedirs(output_dir)

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(root_dir):
    for filename in filenames:
        if any(filename.endswith(ext) for ext in extensions):
            file_path = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
            output_file = os.path.join(output_dir, os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + ".html")
            subprocess.call(["libdoc", file_path, output_file])
```

Will run and stick them all in one folder, made one for each testdoc and libdoc. Save in .py file and run in python

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).